# ¿Como puedo hacer que nadie pueda modificar las variables de mi pagina web?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una pagina web, sobre un juego llamado 'Wordle'. Pero como todas, cuando entro a la consola, me deja modificar las variables.

Ejemplo: Creo una variable llamada 'palabra' en un archivo llamado 'app.js'.

```
var palabra = [];
```

Mi problema es que al entrar a la consola de la pagina web (index.html) puedo modificar esta variable, como cualquier otra persona que entre.

Quisiera saber como hago que nadie las pueda modificar y entrar directamente al codigo interno.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: No es posible. Puedes ofuscar el código en tu sitio o puedes basar todo el funcionamiento en llamados a un servidor asociados a una sesión de usuario.

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Cómo puedo ocultar el codigo y/o basar todo el funcionamiento en un servidor? Gracias.

Comment: Esto es más una cuestión de contexto. En teoría, el usuario debería poder modificar cualquier información en su navegador. Si no quieres que la modifique, usa control de accesos y permisos (con validación de los datos en el backend), y si eso no es suficiente, solo queda no mostrarle la información al usuario. Lo que se ve en el navegador ( en algúnos tipos de arquitecturas) es un estado de la información, y la información util se encuentra almacenada.

Comment: Gracias a Alfabravo y a Legna :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende cual sea tu objetivo... si tu objetivo es que no puedan modificar las variables desde la consola, para eso puedes usar una función anónima para ejecutar tu código.

```js
let siSePuede = "Esta variable la pueden modificar desde la consola";
console.log(siSePuede);

(function x(){
   let noSePuede = "Este mensaje no se puede modificar desde la consola de javascript, porque esta variable pertenece al ambito local a la funcion";
   console.log(noSePuede);
})();
```

Por el contrario, si lo que quieres es ocultar tu código para que nadie lo vea, esa si es mas complicada, pues javascript se usa del lado del cliente, es decir se ejecuta en la máquina que lo usa, por lo tanto es visible para cualquiera.
Lo que puedes hacer como dijo @alfabravo en su comentario, es usar un usar un ofuscador de código, que lo que hará es que no sea fácil de leer ni replicar (aunque no es del todo infalible)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió bastante!